# Are members of a class template instantiated when the class is instantiated?

Tags: c++, c++98

Supposedly members of a template class shouldn't be instantiated unless they are used.
However this sample seems to instantiate the `do_something` member and the `enable_if` fails (which would be expected if we'd instantiated it - but AFAIK we did not).

Am I missing something really basic here?

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

struct some_policy {
    typedef boost::integral_constant<bool, false> condition;
};

struct other_policy {
    typedef boost::integral_constant<bool, true> condition;
};


template <typename policy>
class test {
   void do_something(typename boost::enable_if<typename policy::condition>::type* = 0) {}
};

int main() {
    test<other_policy> p1;
    test<some_policy>  p2;
}
```

[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a06163a630cbdb41)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From C++11 14.7.1/1:

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit
>   instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions

So the function declaration is instantiated; that fails since it depends on an invalid type.

<sub>(Unfortunately, I don't have any historic versions of the standard to hand, but I imagine this rule was similar in C++98)</sub>

Comment: @Niall: Because `enable_if` has no member called `type` when the condition is false.

Comment: Ok, I understand, the boost enable_if expects the type to have an embedded value which it tests for, unlike std enable_if, which just expects the boolean condition.

Answer (score 6):

Mike Seymour already answered why it doesn't work, here's how to workaround it:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

struct some_policy {
    typedef boost::integral_constant<bool, false> condition;
};

struct other_policy {
    typedef boost::integral_constant<bool, true> condition;
};

template <typename policy>
class test {
private:

   template<typename P>
   void do_something_impl(typename boost::enable_if<typename P::condition>::type* = 0) {}

public:
   void do_something()
   {
       do_something_impl<policy>();      
   }
};

int main() {
    test<other_policy> p1;
    test<some_policy>  p2;
}
```

Quick rule of thumb: If you want to do SFINAE, you need a member function *template*.

Answer (score 4):

SFINAE happens only on template function/method (here, it is your class which is template),

You may do in C++11 (default template parameter for function/method):

```
template <typename policy>
class test {
   template <typename T = policy>
   void do_something(typename boost::enable_if<typename T::condition>::type* = 0) {}
};
```

You may alternatively use specialization, something like

```
template <bool> struct helper_do_something {};
template <> struct helper_do_something<true>
{
    void do_something() { /* Your implementation */ }
};

template <typename policy>
class test : helper_do_something<T::condition::value>
{
    // do_something is inherited (and it is present only when T::condition::value is true)
};
```

Comment: No, the Boost version of `enable_if` it takes a type, unlike the C++11 version. `enable_if_c` takes a type.

Comment: (Sorry, that should say "`enable_if_c` takes a **value**". Too late to correct it.)

Comment: @melak47: I have added an other solution which works with C++98 (and without SFINAE).